# Replace every vowels by all the numbers to find the encrypted code

Tags: python, encryption, hashcode

so I have to replace each of the vowels in a list of names to match an encrypted code, so what I need is, for example, for "Andre" I need to get : 0ndr0, 0ndr1, 0ndr2, 0ndr3 ... 1ndr1, 1ndr2 ... 9ndr5 ... 9ndr9

Here is a simplified version of what I have done :

```
def testVoyellePrenom():
    voyelle = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]
    myNumbers = [a + 1 for a in range(-1,9)]
    myNumbers.reverse()
    pre = "ANDRE"
    testing = ""
    for x in pre:
        if(x in voyelle):
            for nb in myNumbers:
                pre = pre.replace(x,str(nb))
                x = str(nb)
                testing = pre
                print(testing)

Output :
9NDRE
8NDRE
7NDRE
6NDRE
5NDRE
4NDRE
3NDRE
2NDRE
1NDRE
0NDRE
0NDR9
0NDR8
0NDR7
0NDR6
0NDR5
0NDR4
0NDR3
0NDR2
0NDR1
0NDR0

Expected output :

...
0NDR0
1NDR9
1NDR8
1NDR7
1NDR6
1NDR5
1NDR4
1NDR3
1NDR2
1NDR1
1NDR0
....
```

Comment: describe what the problem is?

Comment: And, it would be great if you could post a shorter example, which deals with the exact challenge you're facing.

Comment: it makes only once all the numbers for each vowels, as if I have 2 vowels it show me 20 possibilities but I want all possibilities

Comment: @Roy2012 I edited the post with a shorter version

Comment: There are a few problems:

1. The case of the vowels. You are only replacing upper-case vowels. To be efficient, I would recommend turning the entire input into uppercase, e.g. `"ANDRE"`

2. The `x = str(nb)` line is confusing. Why are you setting the vowel to a number? This makes all the other replacements broken.

Comment: Yes I forgot to replace the case of the vowels, but this is not the problem, and for the ```x = str(nb)``` I don't see how I could do it.

Comment: You have changed the expected output. Do you want, e.g. `"ANDR3"` in the expected output?

Comment: Yes I took it off beacause of the caracter limit, thanks for your answers, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct way of doing it:

```
voyelle = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]


def permute_single_index(word, index):
    permutations = []
    word_left = word[0:index]
    word_right = word[index+1:]
    for i in reversed(range(10)):
        permutations.append(f"{word_left}{i}{word_right}")
    return permutations


def testVoyellePrenom(pre):
    upper_pre = pre.upper()
    replace_indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(upper_pre) if x in voyelle]

    permutations = [upper_pre]

    for ri in replace_indexes:
        new_permutations = []
        for word in permutations:
            new_permutations += permute_single_index(word, ri)
        permutations += new_permutations

    print(permutations)
    print(len(permutations))


def main():
    testVoyellePrenom("Andre")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You end up with 121 permutations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution. The basic logic is:

- identify all the locations of vowels (`vowel_inx`).
- Create a cross-product of all the combinations of digits for these locations.
- Loop over this cross product, and create new words by assigning digits to their corresponding location in the original term.

```
    vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]
    pre = "ANDRE"
    import itertools
    vowel_inx = [i for i in range(len(pre)) if pre[i] in vowels ]
    
    ranges = [range(10) for _ in vowel_inx]
    for comb in itertools.product(*ranges):
        pw = list(pre)
        for i in range(len(vowel_inx)):
            pw[vowel_inx[i]] = str(comb[i])
        print ("".join(pw))
```

The output is:

```
0NDR0
0NDR1
0NDR2
0NDR3
0NDR4
0NDR5
0NDR6
0NDR7
0NDR8
0NDR9
1NDR0
1NDR1
1NDR2
...
```

Comment: This solution will not include, e.g. ANDRE, ANDR0, 1NDRE, etc.
You have 100 permutations, there should be 121.

Comment: @PeacefulJames Why do you say 121 combinations? There are two vowels, and you want to replace *each* of them with a digit.

Comment: OK, the OP was edited. It used to have expected output that included, e.g. `"ANDR3"`.   11 * 11 = 121.  and.   (1 vowel + 10 digits ) = 11